# Подгрузка данных Ajax в определенный div

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Создал 3 файлика:

1. fn.php
2. script.js
3. index.php

В fn.php вставил следующий код:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'){
    if (isset($_REQUEST['catname'])){
        $catname = $_REQUEST['catname'];
        echo select_cat($catname);
    }
}
function select_cat($select_cat){
    echo $select_cat;
}
?>
```

В script.js

```
function get_category(catname){
    var catname = catname;
    $("#result").html('<img src="loader.gif" />');
    $("#result").load("fn.php", { catname: catname });
}
```

В index.php

```
<div class="r" onclick="get_category('catname');">Click Me</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Этот весь код работает... jQuery подключен... Вопрос: как добавить эффект того, что 1 див скажем плавно появляется, или выезжает... вообщем, как к коду добавить эфект и реально ли вообще это сделать.

Answer (score 3):

Выбирайте любой из [эффектов и анимации](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B)

**UPD:**

```
var sidebar_next = $("#sidebar_next");
    if(sidebar_next.hasClass('afterAnimation')){
        sidebar_next.animate({ marginLeft: "0px" }, 500).removeClass('afterAnimation');
    }
    else {
        sidebar_next.animate({ marginLeft: "175px" }, 500).addClass('afterAnimation');
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло... теперь сразу ещё один вопросик, если можно:
Я сделал так:

    function get_category(catname){
 var catname = catname;
 $("#sidebar_next").animate({ marginLeft: "175px" }, 500);
 $("#sidebar_next").load("fn.php", {catname: catname});
    }

Теперь у меня срабатывает при первом клике выезд... как сделать так чтоб, при последующих кликах сначала объект заезжал, а потом выезжал обратно?

Comment: Самый простой способ это добавлять в конце действия класс, а потом делать проверку на него, добавил в ответ свой вариант

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").toggle(
function(){ $("#mydiv").show();},
function(){ $("#mydiv").hide();}
);
```

Вот так при клике на кнопке с id="mydiv" будет то появляться, то исчезать mydiv

Comment: немного не то... это меняет поочереди событие... а мне надо:
1-й клик: действия: выехал блок - вывело информацию в нем
2-й клик: действия: заехал блок - выехал блок - вывело информацию в нем
3-й клик: действия: заехал блок - выехал блок - вывело информацию в нем
4-й клик переход на главную: действия: заехал блок

Comment: Ну пишите эффекты цепочкой, тут вы или сделали вывод из того, что вам здесь предложили, или вам еще рано такое писать :)